# Error with rspec testing

Tags: rspec, terminal

ok, so here's the deal. Going over the Rails tutorial. We're running a testing environment to make sure that the things we want showing up on our pages are making it. Doing this using pages_controller_spec.rb file. And this is one of three arguments that we passed:

```
describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should has_selector("title", 
                  :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
    end
```

All three tests are the same. When I run rspec spec/ from the command line (I'm using windows vista) I get this error on all three tests:

1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mresponse.should have_selector("title",←[0m
←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
←[31mundefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x4d71bd8>←[0m
←[36m # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in`block (3 levels)
in '←[0m

As you can see, I am not using anything called has_selector, but have_selector. Where is this coming from? Does anyone know how to fix it? I've checked over the code repeatedly for 2 days now to make sure that my example matches the video and that the text being checked for by rspec is identical on the actual web pages. I mean, heck, the pages even display properly after I start the server. So I am totally without a clue. The closest I came to an answer was on another forum where someone mentioned that they forgot to include the 'render_views' near the top after the first 'describe'. Double checked that too and I got it where it needs to be. *sad programmer*

(edit) After talking to someone else, they said that it looks like the method hasn't been loaded by ruby. This makes sense to me given the line in the output about "no method defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your question has a typo, since it does say `should has_selector`. But assuming your spec says `should have_selector`, your problem is that RSpec does not have any such matcher.

You may be looking at some example code that assumes you're using a package like webrat or [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). These gems work with rspec to support certain kinds of tests, and each one comes with a `has_selector?` method (which spec turns into `should have_selector`).

I recommend capybara; once it's installed, you can do the following (note that [capybara expects :text](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers%3ahas_selector?) instead of :content):

```
response.should have_selector("title", 
  :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
```

Comment: Good idea. After getting capybara up and running the output changed to this: 


  '1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mresponse.should have_selector("title",←[0m
       ←[31mexpected css "title" to return something←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels)
in <top (required)>'←[0m'

Still not sure why it's saying that it expects css "title" to return something. I'm gonna keep messing around with the code some. See what happens with the :text thing.

Comment: Ok, I'm fed up with this. Going back over the project, I'm seeing a lot of inconsistencies. That's what I got for using a screen cast and then trying to figure out the bugs via an updated book of the screen cast. (Michael Hartl) I'll just start it over with the book this time. Sorry to be a pain and waste your time. I should have done this in the first place. (even if I did learn quite a bit extra)